# SpringBoot application doesn't autowire field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I do have ServiceImpl which looks like this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {
private final String fieldA;
@Override 
public boolean isFieldA(String text){
return fieldA.equals(text);
}
```

And I would like to inject a field value to fieldA in an Application.java from application.yml like this:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
@Value("${fieldA}")
private String fieldA;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
@Bean
public ServiceA serviceA() {
    return new ServiceAImpl(fieldA);
}
```

But I receive the following error when running SpringBoot app:

> Error creating bean with name 'serviceAImpl' defined in URLNo qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: try using qualifier

Answer (score 2):

You annotated your class with `@Service` and defined it manually as a bean with the `@Bean` annotation. I do think the second is the way you planned to use it.
The `@Service` annotation will make this class get picked up by Spring's component scan and additionally create an instance of it.
Of course it tries to resolve the parameters and fails when it tries to find a matching "bean" for the String field because there is no simple String bean (and should not :) ).

Remove the `@Service` annotation and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You're using two bean declaration mechanisms:

1. You're registering your bean using `@Service`
2. You're registering a bean using `@Bean`

This means that your service will be created twice. The one defined using `@Bean` works properly, since it uses the `@Value` annotation to inject the proper value in your service.

However, the service created due to `@Service` doesn't know about the `@Value` annotation and will try to find any bean of type `String`, which it can't find, and thus it will throw the exception you're seeing.

Now, the solution is to pick either one of these. If you want to keep the `@Bean` configuration, you should remove the `@Service` annotation from `ServiceAImpl` and that will do the trick.

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `@Service` annotation, you should remove the `@Bean` declaration, and you should write your own constructor rather than relying on Lombok because this allows you to use the `@Value` annotation within the constructor:

```java
@Service
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {
    private final String fieldA;

    /**
     * This constructor works as well
     */
    public ServiceAImpl(@Value("${fieldA}") String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean isFieldA(String text){
        return fieldA.equals(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaciejPapurzyński which solution did you choose? Did you remove the `@Service` annotation or did you remove the `@Bean`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Service
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA { 
    private final String fieldA;

    @Autowire
    public ServiceAImpl(@Value("${fieldA}") String fieldA){
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean isFieldA(String text){
        return fieldA.equals(text);
    }
}
```

and this

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

You should not use `@Service` and `@Bean` for the same class!

Answer (score 1):

Spring is not so smart :)

You should annotate your bean like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceAImpl {
     @Value("${fieldA}")
     private final String something;
...
```

But I'm not sure it will work with the `@RequiredFieldsConstructor`, it would be simpler for you write down the constructor annotated with `@Autowired` and using the `@Value` annotation for the `String` parameter:

```
@Autowired
public ServiceAImpl(@Value("${aProp}") String string) {
```

Comment: Small note, the `@Autowired` annotation isn't necessary any longer for constructors since Spring 4.3/Spring boot 1.3 (at least if you have only one constructor).

Comment: That error message is given fromthe fact that it is trying to autowire the constructor parameter with the spring beans, but if you need to pass that string as a `@Value` you need to put the annotation in the contructor argument, but if it is generated by lombok it can't put that annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare `ServiceAImpl` as a Spring bean in your Java Configuration file, you should remove the `@Service` annotation from the class declaration. These annotations doesn't work well together.

**ServiceAImpl.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {

    private final String fieldA;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceAImpl(String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFieldA(String text) {
        return fieldA.equals(text);
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Value("${fieldA}")
    private String fieldA;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceA serviceA() {
        return new ServiceAImpl(fieldA);
    }
}
```

Your **application.properties**

```
fieldA=value
```

Answer (score 0):

The below implementation works well for me. You have two issues, first you have to choose between @Service and @Bean and the other issue I've seen in your code was the @Value annotation, you have to use only to inject a value from the properties.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestedValueApplication {

    @Autowired
    void printServiceInstance(ServiceA service) {

        System.out.println("Service instance: " + service);
        System.out.println("value==value? " + service.isFieldA("value"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestedValueApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceA serviceA(@Value("${fieldA}") String fieldA) {
        return new ServiceAImpl(fieldA);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {

    private String fieldA;

    ServiceAImpl(String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    public boolean isFieldA(String text) {
        return fieldA.equals(text);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
fieldA=value
```